# How to implement Linear Sarsa

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

How do you implement "**Linear Sarsa**" in Python?

I've included a pseudocode example, for those not familiar with the algorithm, and my personal attempt at implementing it in Python.

## Pseudocode example of the Linear Sarsa algorithm:

1. Initialize θ arbitrarily
2. for each i in {1, . . . , N} do
3. s ← initial state for episode i
4. while state s is not terminal do
5. a ← π(s)
6. r ← observed reward for action a at state s
7. s0 ← observed next state for action a at state s
8. θ ← θ + α[r + γV(s0; θ) − V(s; θ)]∇θV(s; θ)
9. s ← s0
10. end while
11. end for

## Attempted Python Implementation

```py
def linear_sarsa(env, max_episodes, eta, gamma, epsilon, seed=None):
    random_state = np.random.RandomState(seed)
    eta = np.linspace(eta, 0, max_episodes)
    epsilon = np.linspace(epsilon, 0, max_episodes)
    theta = np.zeros(env.n_features)

    for i in range(max_episodes):
        features = env.reset()
        q = features.dot(theta)
        gradientThetaFeatures = np.gradient(q[s]) #∇θV(s; θ)
        done = False
        while not done:
            s2, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
            action1 = policy
            #Theta Value
            #θ ← θ + α[r + γV(s2; θ) − V(s; θ)]∇θV(s; θ)
            theta = theta + eta * (reward + (gamma * q[s2]) - q[s]) * gradientThetaFeatures
            s = s2
    return theta
```

Am I doing this correctly?